# how to automatically rename remote image name when downloading image by right click save as method?

Tags: php, javascript, rename

This is the way i pull instagram images using ajax get method from instegram api. I want rename the image when user right click on image .For example if the name of image is
**435345345243254_7.jpg** i want to change it to **435345345243254_7(david).jpg** when user right click and try to save it . Could any one tell me how i can do this ?

**Note :** looking for a solution for firefox and iphone safari browser.

method i display the images at start:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

$(".instagram").append("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>"); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the filename if the client is saving a file by right click, save as.

However, you could modify your anchor (e.g. give it another GET parameter) to trigger a download on your **backend**, including a `Content-Disposition` header with a different filename:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="435345345243254_7(david).jpg"');
```

*In case you are using PHP*

Edit: I just Googled it to verify my answer, there are [a lot of discussions](https://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=filename%20right%20click%20save%20as) going on about it.

Comment: Thanks for reply . so you mean i need to create a button next to each image thumbnail and once user click on that a php script start downloading that for me and rename it for me ? but how i can call php to do this for me ?

Comment: You already have an `a`nchor tag surrounding your image. I'd use this instead of an additional button - but thats up to you. So change the `href` to a PHP script, which will set the header as seen in my answer + send the image to the client. You might want to ask Google on [how to send a file with php](https://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=how%20to%20send%20a%20file%20with%20php).

Comment: so you mean i should do like this :<a target='_blank' href='./downloadimage.php?imageurl=" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"'> ? what should i put in downloadimage.php so it change the image name and promt the user to save it ?